# How to only make one user authenticate via SSH keys and allow password authentication to all others

Tags: ssh, configuration, authentication

I was wondering if it would be possible to only force SSH key based authentication to one user (admin) and allow all other users on the system (excluding root, who's ssh login is already disabled in sshd_config) to authenticate via Password.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that by modifying your `sshd_config` to add:

```
Match User <username>
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

You can do the same for groups as well by using `Match Group` instead

Don't forget to restart `sshd` after

Comment: Is there any way to just have that as a catch-all for all users except a certain one? i,e admin?

Comment: @DavidRazdolski `Match Users` can negate a match `Match User *,!admin`

Comment: @DavidRazdolski That is possible by negation but note that [it's broken in certain releases of OpenSSH](https://superuser.com/questions/952235/why-arent-my-negative-matches-working)